# Replacing le with gli

Tags: pronouns

I've read that 'le' (to her) can be replaced by 'gli' in speech. How often does this happen, and in what contexts?

Example: Le dico qualcosa (a Laura). Gli dico qualcosa (a Laura).

Comment: Would you allow a little humor? Since the most recent tendency is to make Italian language (as English and other languages) as neutral as possible, saying and writing **lei/lui**, "ti sei trovat' bene?", "ti sei divertit**ǝ**?", well, it might be that in the near future we would say something like "**Glile** dico qualcosa" or, like the Venetian below, "**Ghe** dico qualcosa"  :-)

Answer (score 4):

The usage of *gli* for the dative case of the third person clitic personal pronoun is very common in speech and informal writing, despite it being considered inappropriate in formal writing.

From the [*Grammatica Italiana Treccani*](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/gli-o-le_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/):

> Per indicare il complemento di termine è sempre più comune, nel parlato e nello scritto informale, l’uso della forma pronominale atona *gli*, sia per il maschile, sia per il femminile (al posto di *le*) [...]
>
> L’uso di un’unica forma è largamente attestato nel corso della nostra storia linguistica ed è conforme all’etimologia (la forma latina *illi* era sia maschile, sia femminile). Tuttavia quest’uso non è ancora accettato nella norma, e gli al posto di le viene percepito come forma popolare, familiare e colloquiale, da evitare soprattutto nello scritto formale.

> To indicate the indirect object it is more and more common, both in speech and in informal writing, the usage of the pronominal clitic form *gli*, both for the masculine and for the feminine (instead of *le*). [...]
>
> The usage of a single form is largely attested in our linguistic history and conformal to the etymology (the Latin form *illi* was both masculine and feminine). However this usage is not yet accepted as a rule, and *gli* instead of *le* is perceived as a popular form, familiar and colloquial, to be avoided especially in the formal writing.

---

However, Serianni in his book *Italiano* (VII.38) takes a much stronger view and declares the usage of *gli* in the feminine form "certainly to avoid, even in informal speech" (while being much more indulgent towards the usage of *gli* instead of *loro*), although noting that this usage is very common even in literary texts. In my experience this position does not represent the actual usage of the speakers, but I wanted to report it anyway given the high prestige of Serianni's book.

---

As usual in these cases I advise a learner to always use *le*, but to be prepared to encounter *gli* very often in the texts and speech of other people.

Comment: “Prevalent” and “completely superseded” sound like exaggerations. As always, this depends on geographical areas and so on. _Gli_ for _loro_ is on its way to be widespread, but in my experience _gli_ for _le_ is still quite limited and, more importantly, connotes negatively who uses it.

Comment: @DaG I moderated the language in this answer, but note that even Serianni (who is highly critical of this usage of *gli*) notes that it is very present even in literary texts, from Boccaccio to Moravia.

Comment: May I suggest to change the Treccani link with the following one? https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/gli-o-le_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi Thank you, you're right this is better!

Comment: @DaG I thought about it, and maybe the difference in perception can be explained in the different substratum? For example in Venetian there's only one third person indirect pronoun (*ghe*), and the fact that the regional language still has a high prestige (in the linguistic sense) might influence the usage of that construction in spoken Italian. I do not know how things work in Roman, but it would be an explanation for the difference we perceived.

Answer (score 1):

If you heard this, it was a mistake.
Italian has strictly rules on this, so the personal pronoun (the one that goes instead of the noun) is always "le" referring to "her" (a lei) as in this case, and "gli" referring to "him" (a lui).

"Gli dico qualcosa (a Laura)" is a mistake.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! However I disagree, it might be a mistake in formal writing but in informal writing and speech the use of *gli* for the feminine third person complement pronoun is the most common form.

Comment: @DenisNardin, do you have source for “the most common form”? In my experience it isn't at all.

Comment: @DaG I added an answer with a quote from the Grammatica Italiana Treccani exactly for this reason. I will revise a little my language to account for your comments but that's my experience (with the caveat I haven't lived in Italy for a while now)

Comment: You should tell this to Manzoni, who used it, in line with many other authors. Of course, in a term paper in primary school such usage of *gli* would be marked as an error. At some point grammarians arbitrarily decided for *le*, but this has been somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: We all agree that he just asked about contemporary italian, in forms of speech, and not about the linguistic history, so no Manzoni, Boccaccio, Moravia, Dante, and all the remarkable authors. Just italian spoken. "gli" for "her" is wrong. You can use it ? For sure. Just, it's wrong.

Comment: @RobyB, I was with you until I read the Treccani article. I have never said "gli" referring to a woman (Bari origin here :-). But it seems that language does change! Also, please consider that OP was not asking about rules, but about its usage "in speech", asking about how often this happens and in what contexts, just what the Treccani explains.